# No puedo convertir a un ARRAY los datos de un archivo JSON (FETCH()) en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, json

Buen dia. Tengo un problemac con Javascript. Hago uso de la funcion fecth() para tomar el archivo json de un servidor. Bueno practicamente si me refleja los mismos datos en la consola del navegador, pero la cosa es que quiero tomar esos archivos, como Array, como es lo natural, para poder iterar y colocarlos en elementos para mostrarlos por HTML.
Pero e problema es que no puedo iterar la data, ni puedo convertirlo a ARRAY. Ya probe funciones como parse o map pero nada. Esto es el codigo primitivo para hacer eso, estan unos comentarios de lineas que intentaba, pero la variable que contiene los datos no me lo reconoce como ARRAY, por ende no puedo iterar.

```
  fetch("https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/coins?skip=0&limit=5&currency=EUR")

    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      //conversion de object a array (pero no me convierte a array)
      // const propertyValues = Object.entries(result);
      // console.log(propertyValues[1]); Queria probar accedeiendo al primero elemento, pero no es un array
      // console.log(result[1].id);
      result.forEach(post => {
        objeto.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
      })
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error'));
```

Imagen de la consola

[image: Hago la conversion a ARRAY, pero me salta al CATCH, el cual me muestra mensaje de ERROR]

ACTUALIZADO, es verdad, lo que tengo que hacer es acceder al objeto interno, pero tego otro problema, ya revise tantas paginas que perdi la cuenta, y es el problema que no puede adjuntar informacion en etiquetas que creo mismo en el javascript. Ayudenme porfavor, con algo tan simple ya me vuelvo loco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que recorrer result.coins No el result, ya que coins es el que trae la lista

```js
fetch("https://api.coinstats.app/public/v1/coins?skip=0&limit=5&currency=EUR")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
      result.coins.forEach(post => {
        console.log(post);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

```html
<div id="objeto"></div>
```